# React: setState not updating?

Tags: reactjs, axios, state, router, setstate

I'm trying to update the state after a successful login attempt and the state is not being updated and the rest of the code after the setstate isn't being called either?

```
console.log(`test`) // THIS GETS CALLED
this.setState({
   userinfo: {
      id: res.data._id,
      username: res.data.username,
      email: res.data.email,
      avatar: res.data.avatar,
      favpacks: res.data.favpacks,
   },
   signedin: true
})
console.log(`test22`)  // THIS DOESNT GETS CALLED
console.log(this.state)  // THIS DOESNT GETS CALLED
```

**EDIT: Showing more code for ref**

Code example is located in the "UserInfo" function below

```
class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super()
    this.state = {
      show: false,
      modalId: '',
      modaldata: undefined,
      serverstatus: socket.connected,
      signedin: false,
      userinfo: {}
    }

    console.log(`Socket connected: ${socket.connected}`)

    this.showModal = this.showModal.bind(this)
    this.hideModal = this.hideModal.bind(this)
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.UserInfo()
  }

  async UserInfo() {
    console.log('im here')

    const id = localStorage.getItem(`id`)

    await axios.get(`/Auth/${id}`, {
      headers: { 'auth-token': localStorage.getItem(`auth-token`) }
    })
    .then(async res => {
      console.log(res)
    
      if(res.data.errorcode == 400) {
        let err = res.data.error
        if(err.name === `TokenExpiredError`) {
          console.warn(`Error: JWT Expired, Please log in again.`)

          toast.error('Login session expired: Please log in again.', {
            position: "top-center",
            autoClose: 5000,
            hideProgressBar: false,
            closeOnClick: true,
            pauseOnHover: true,
            draggable: true,
            progress: undefined,
          })
        }
      } else {
        console.log(`hellogoodnight`)
        console.log(typeof res)
        this.setState({
          userinfo: {
            id: res.data._id,
            username: res.data.username,
            email: res.data.email,
            avatar: res.data.avatar,
            favpacks: res.data.favpacks,
          },
          signedin: true
        })
        console.log(`test22`)
        console.log(this.state)
      }
    })
    .catch(err => {
      if(err.data === `jwt expired`) {
      }
    })
  }

  showModal = async (modalId, modaldata) => {
    console.log(modalId, modaldata)
    console.log(this.state)
    this.setState({
      show: true,
      modalId: modalId,
      modaldata: modaldata
    })
    console.log(this.state)
  }

  hideModal = async () => {
    this.setState({
      show: false,
    })
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.setState({
        show: false,
        modalId: '',
        modaldata: null
      })
    }, 450)
  }



  render() {
    socket.on(`/server/connected`, ((req, res) => {
      console.log(`Socket connected: ${socket.connected}`)
      this.setState({
        serverstatus: socket.connected
      })
    }))

    console.log(this.state.serverstatus)
    return (
      <BrowserRouter>
        <Header signedin={this.state.signedin} userinfo={this.state.userinfo} showModal={this.showModal} serverstat={this.state.serverstatus} />
        <Switch>
          <Route path="/" render={() => (
            <Lobbies />
          )} exact />
        </Switch>
        <ToastContainer />
        <Modal UserInfo={this.UserInfo} modaldata={this.state.modaldata} modalId={this.state.modalId} showModal={this.showModal} hideModal={this.hideModal} show={this.state.show} />
      </BrowserRouter>
    )
  }
}
```

*i call the function from the sign in modal below*
Using this.props.UserInfo

```
SISubmit (e) {
        e.preventDefault()
        window.grecaptcha.ready(() => {
            window.grecaptcha.execute(`MY CAPTCHA KEY`,
            {
                    action: 'login'
            })
            .then(token => {
                axios.post(`Auth/Login`, {
                    'g-recaptcha-response': token,
                    emailuser: this.SignInInputs.emailuser.current.value,
                    pass: this.SignInInputs.pass.current.value
                })
                .then(res => {
                    localStorage.setItem("auth-token", res.data.token)
                    localStorage.setItem("expiry", Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000) + 60 * 60)
                    localStorage.setItem("id", res.data.id)
                    this.props.UserInfo()
                })
                .catch(err => {
                    console.log(err)
                })
            })
        })
    }
```

Comment: Can you see any errors in console in dev tools? We'll need more than this, can you provide whole component code?

Comment: No errors, just stops logging after the first console log :/

Comment: does the res.data datatype is object?

Comment: Perhaps you have some other console.log("test") in your code, and this code you show here are never called. Can you change it to console.log("hellogoodnight") and see if the log updates?

Comment: Or maybe the code is wrapped in a try catch statement?

Comment: The test log is that one, just confirmed and the "res" is an object, just checked again using typeof.  It's not wrapped in a try catch statement however it is wrapped in a axios request (which might be still idk) This code is wrapped in the "then" function

Comment: Are the other logs logged if you remove the setState?

Comment: Please show your whole component.

Comment: Updated the post to show more of my code for you, also yes the other logs are called if i remove setstate

Comment: then one of the value in the setState might be throwing error.. log those values to see

Comment: It is wrapped in a try catch really... Log the `err` inside of the catch.

Comment: ah, getting an error in that now. Getting this: 

`TypeError: this.setState is not a function
    at App.jsx:87
    at async Object.UserInfo (App.jsx:63)`

Comment: Try to add `this.UserInfo = this.UserInfo.bind(this)` in the constructor.

Comment: It's been a while since I worked with class components. I recommend you to move over to using functional components, it's way cleaner.

Comment: Thank you so much, that fixed it. Also yeah I've heard that so I might. Just starting to learn react so im better changing sooner rather than later lol. Thank you so much again <3

Comment: No problem :) You should definitely start asap! Good luck